# How do I remove the dark blue that is used in tig in cygwin?

Tags: git, terminal, cygwin, tig

I have looked all over google and I am still unable to find the config param to get rid of the dark blue that is used by tig in the cygwin terminal.  The Dark Blue just like when it is used in ls can be difficult to read and peruse.

Does anyone know how to change this setting?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color in your `~/.tigrc` file. From version 2.0 all colors are documented in the system `tigrc` file. Take a look at the [color section](https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/5d53d2ddb26fc40d0e8d37c4f8eb6df2af492854/tigrc#L269) to get an idea of where blue is used. In older versions, you need to refer to the tigrc man page to see the color supported names. The default color settings are only "configured in the source code.

Alternatively, you could also change make the dark blue color more readable in the Cygwin terminal itself. For example, take a look at https://superuser.com/a/444766.

Comment: `color date red default` and `color graph-commit green default` fixed it for me, based on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin uses the mintty terminal emulator by default, which doesn't seem to give the ability to customize its colors. You might want to switch to [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/); it does offer this ability. I know of at least one legible color scheme, [Solarized](https://github.com/stevenharman/console2-solarized), available for it; but you may be able to find others.

Comment: Does Console2 provide similar tools to Cygwin?

Comment: No; I believe you have to have Cygwin installed along with it if you want POSIX functionality.